# ParamConverter serializing uninitialized object

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

Using a [`ParamConverter`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) to get an object, seems to give an "uninitialized" instance of it.

The object is partially loaded, ie: its relations are not fetched from the database.

Let me give an example:

```
Article
    title
    body
    comments (Collection of Comment)
```

If I want a controller the `Comment`s of a given `Article` I'd do this

```php
/**
 * @Route("/article/{id}/comments",
 *     name="article_comments",
 *     defaults={"_format": "json"}
 * )
 * @ParamConverter("article", class="AppBundle:Article")
 */
public function purchaseOrderGetAction(Article $article)
{
    return new JsonResponse($article->getComments());
}
```

This won't send anything because the `Article` does not seem to be fully loaded.

```
dump($article);
```

Gives

```
DefaultController.php on line 42:
Article {#1186 ▼
  -id: 1
  -title: "My awesome article"
  -body: "Here is the story of..."
  -comments: PersistentCollection {#1224 ▼}
    -snapshot: []
    -owner: Article {#1186}
    -association: array:15 [ …15]
    -em: EntityManager {#936 …11}
    -backRefFieldName: "article"
    -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#1213 …}
    -isDirty: false
    #collection: ArrayCollection {#1225 ▼
      -elements: []
    }
    #initialized: false
  }
}
```

As you can see, there is nothing loaded on the `details` field.

Do I have to load the whole object manually or is there some way to load only the required `comments` from the database ?

Answer (score 0):

I forced the lazy loading on `details` with

```php
return new JsonResponse($article->getComments()->toArray());
```

It actually generates as much queries as it has `Comment` + 1 for the `Article` but I didn't find better.